# Error when looping through a collection

Tags: c#

With this code:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, double> FlowInformation = new Dictionary<DateTime, double>();

foreach (DateTime key in FlowInformation)
{
    if (initialialrec != 0)
    {
        if (FlowInformation[key] > initialialrec)
            flow = key.ToShortDateString() + " " + key.ToShortTimeString() + "+";

        if (FlowInformation[key] < initialialrec)
            flow = key.ToShortDateString() + " " + key.ToShortTimeString()+"-";

        initialialrec = FlowInformation[key];
        file.WriteLine(flow);
    }

    FlowInformation.Clear();                    
}
```

I get a compilation error:

```
Strategy\theFlowStrategy.cs Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair' to 'System.DateTime'
```

How can I iterate though this collection?

Comment: You want to iterate over the keys in the dictionary, so you want to call `Keys` on the dictionary. Right now you would be iterating over the key-value pairs in the dictionary, which are of type `KeyValuePair<DateTime, double>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Generic dictionary is a list of `KeyValuePair` items.

To loop on the keys (as you are trying to do), then loop on `FlowInformation.Keys`. You can also loop on the values directly using `FlowInformation.Values`.

The other thing you could do is to use `KeyValuePair` as your iteration variable type. That will save you having to do `FlowInformation[key]` to find out which value corresponds to your key, as the value will be in the `.Value` property of the iteration variable.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
  foreach (DateTime key in FlowInformation)
```

is incorrect. As the error message states, your dictionary does not contain DateTime objects, it contains KeyValuePair objects.

There are a few ways around this.
One option is to iterate through the dicitonary's *Keys*, which are indeed DateTime objects.

```
foreach (DateTime key in FlowInformation.Keys)
```

Another option is to iterate through the KeyValuePair objects in the dictionary, and extract the keys as you need them.

```
 foreach (var kvp in FlowInformation)
 {
     DateTime key = kvp.Key;
     ...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

A `Dictionary<T,T>` contains a list of `KeyValuePair<T,T>`.

I don't know your whole code, but I'm supposing that `initialrec` is a number (`double`) and `flow` is a string.
Check this out:

```
        Dictionary<DateTime, double> FlowInformation = new Dictionary<DateTime, double>();

        double initialialrec;
        string flow;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<DateTime, double> Entry in FlowInformation)
        {
            if (initialialrec != 0)
            {
                if (Entry.Value > initialialrec)
                    flow = Entry.Key.ToShortDateString() + " " + Entry.Key.ToShortTimeString() + "+";

                if (Entry.Value < initialialrec)
                    flow = Entry.Key.ToShortDateString() + " " + Entry.Key.ToShortTimeString() + "-";

                initialialrec = Entry.Value;
                file.WriteLine(flow);
            }
        }
```

You can't call that `Clear` inside the loop, though.